# What is the MySQL monitor?

Tags: mysql

Upon a successful connection to the MySQL server, the client is greeted with "Welcome to the MySQL monitor". A web search returned many results on monitoring for MySQL databases. Is "monitor" here another name for "server"?

Comment: I believe "monitor" is something to do with the client, not the server, and that line is output by the client. Though I haven't been able to find definitive references for the term.

Answer (score 1):

It is sometimes called the "commandline mysql tool".  It is a client that comes with MySQL and MariaDB.  It is a simple but very useful way to type SQL and get it executed.  Think of it as the "shell" version of phpmyadmin or Workbench.

It does not do any monitoring, though it could be used as a way to execute SQL in a monitoring script.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this - I don't suppose the "monitor" name is used or introduced in any documentation anymore?

Comment: @rishai - I don't recall seeing it.  (But I might have ignored it.)